# Setting up braintree for managing payments with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sdk, braintree, gateway

I am trying to set up Braintree to manage payments in Laravel, and I am having a really hard time.
I tried to follow a tutorial online by setting the gateway in AppServiceProvider in Laravel.

The problem is that I continue to have an error with undefined type Braintree\Gateway although i already installed the SDK with:

```
composer require braintree/braintree_php
```

This is my code:

```
$this->app->singleton(Gateway::class, function($app){
        return new Gateway(
            [
                'enviroment' => 'sandbox',
                'merchantId'=> 'fcbw9x3mcdzygrq8',
                'publicKey' => 'bgzxhtjd5zfhh7fn',
                'privateKey' => 'f55752441b22915c8c10b437a3e4376d'
            ]
            );
    });
```

I even imported it with:

```
use Braintree\Gateway;
```

What am I doing wrong?